# Property of the Fourier transform in Schwartz space

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F: S(\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the function that associates to the function $f$ its Fourier transform $\hat f$.

Is it a bijection in the Schwartz space?

Comment: Yes it is, See Read & Simon Mathematical Physics Volume II

Comment: This is the "Schwartz" with a "t"... :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one can note that the [Fourier Inversion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem) still holds for continuous functions that are integrable. Since $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the Schwarz functions are indeed integrable.

Comment: No, I don't think so. OP is already assuming/knows that the Fourier transform of a Schwarz function is Schwarz. Hence, they right $F:\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The question is whether this operator is invertible.

Comment: Oh yep I misinterpreted the question with the way it was worded!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Fourier transform is a bijection on Schwartz functions. In fact, it is a homeomorphism for the Frechet space topology on Schwartz functions.

The keyword(s) to google for related stuff is "Fourier inversion (transform)"... which gives a two-sided inverse to Fourier transform.

The proof can be found many places. Letting $F$ be Fourier transform and $I$ the inverse transform, the heuristic for the proof of Fourier inversion is
$$
I(Ff)(x) \;=\; \int e^{2\pi ix\xi} Ff(\xi)\;d\xi
\;=\; \int e^{2\pi ix\xi}\int e^{-2\pi i \xi t}f(t)\;dt\;d\xi
$$
$$
=_{???}\; \int f(t) \Big(\int e^{2\pi i\xi(x-t)}\;d\xi\Big)dt
\;=_{???} \int f(t)\,\delta_{x-t}\;dt 
\;=\; f(x)
$$
An immediate problem is that the interchange of integrals is not justified. However, if we are able to believe that the inner integral is $\delta_{x-t}$ (Dirac delta), then this does produce the correct outcome.

To make this into a proof, insertion of a dummy Schwartz function is the usual ploy...